# Docker for Windows to host IIS Server - what is the path?

Tags: windows, iis, docker

Looking for the path to package an asp.net app in IIS in a docker container.

The docs/examples we have seen so far show how to package a windows application (and by extension, windows service) in a docker container:

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-704
- https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_two/

From that, we can see how to package an apache server along with our app in a docker container.

But what we do not see are docs / vision to embed IIS instance (with our app installed in it) in a docker container.

Where to find such docs/examples?

(We have an asp.net app on IIS 8.5 / .NET 4.51)

Comment: You are referring to the "technical preview" of Windows Server 2016?

Comment: @Bryan I am asking "how to do Z?" The answer might be: "Use Windows version X, and follow doc Y" (or whatever). I am just asking the question... you tell me the answer!

Comment: Well, that's very generous of you; if you could just expand a little on "I see how to package a windows service in a docker container" - where did you see that; was it referring to the technical preview or some other version of Windows?

Comment: @Bryan Sorry, You are right. I should have had a bit more background on there. OP enhanced.

Comment: Thanks.  The docker.com link relates to running Linux-based containers, albeit from a Windows client.  I recommend https://blog.docker.com/2015/08/tp-docker-engine-windows-server-2016/ for an update and https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-windows-server-2016-containers-preview for more recent info on Windows Server containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is what you are after:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/live/windows-container-samples/iis

> **Sample to create a Windows Server Container Image with IIS 10.0 enabled**
>
> These samples were created for Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 3 with Containers. They assume that the WindowsServerCore Container base image is present.

Comment: Yup, at this time, the only way to create a windows docker image is to use Win2016-CTP3 and steps like those documented.

Answer (score 2):

The sample Bryan posted is a great resource (that's the Hyper-V GitHub account so we do track issues and requests there).

In addition, we used IIS as the default workload for our Windows Server Container and Hyper-V Container quickstart guides.  Here are step by step instructions for Server TP4:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker.

Comment: The link is broken, do you have another?